# JqPlot canvasOverlay problems in Chrome

Tags: jqplot

I found the canvasOverlay [example](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/canvas-overlay.html) don't show in Chrome but in Firefox and IE is fine.
What's the problem? How to show it in Chrome.

[image: in Firefox and IE]
[image: in Chrome]

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @YosepKim I uninstall my Chrome, then install the latest version. The problem is solved.